# Number of paths in a complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm aware of the previous question which has been answered : [Number of unique paths in a complete graph with n verticies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457449/number-of-unique-paths-in-a-complete-graph-with-n-verticies)

Today   , I found another formula for the number of paths between two vertices in a complete graph

> $     \space \ \lfloor e \times (p-2) !\rfloor $

such that $p$ is number of vertices in complete graph . I don't know how $e$ and floor function have appeared in that . In the other words , I'm looking for the proof .

Comment: Did you personally find the formula, or did you find it given somewhere? I only ask because I'd be a little concerned, if you found it through "pattern matching" yourself, that it might not always be the correct count. I could imagine the power series for $e$ giving something like this though, so it does seem plausible.

Comment: Why don't you tell us where you found that formula?

Comment: @bof I found it in a non-English . Unfortunately it doesn't have translation and online version .

Comment: Similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406920/total-number-paths-between-two-nodes-in-a-complete-graph/2406927#2406927